# How to acess Wamp Server from another computer

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, lan

How can i access my local wamp server on another computer

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    #Deny from all
    Allow from all    
</Directory>
```

i used this code in httpd.config file but not work..
and i also turn off the firewall setting

Comment: What do you mean access?? If you just want to visit the server url (apps) then you dont need to do anything, just make sure your wamp server computer is on same network or public network and from other computer just enter IP address of the wamp server computer on browser. If the IP address of your wamp server computer is 192.168.10.10 then from other computer you can access via IP address on browser that all

Comment: i entered ipaddress/projectname but it's showing not found and my computers is on same network

Comment: yes i have turned on

Comment: yehhh bro i have already turnned it off

Comment: ok what you get when you visit your IP only from your browser of another computer? not found or apache home page?? or your custom page???

Comment: i m getting this - Not Found the requested URL/ was not found on this server